# HTML form doesn't contain a form submit button name when using the Enter key

Tags: html, forms, asp.net-mvc-3

My ASP.NET MVC 3 website has code on the server side that checks for the name of the submit button clicked to submit the form.  The code works when I use the mouse to click the button, but when I use the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, the form gets posted, but the request doesn't contain the name of the submit button.

Is there some attribute I can set on the submit button to get this to work for both clicking and using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div>Search:</div>
  <form action="/Item/Search" method="post">
    <input class="fulltextsearch" id="FTSearchText" name="FTSearchText" type="text" value="" />
     <input type="submit" value="Go" name="FTSearchButton" />
  </form>
</div>
```

On the server side, I have a custom model binder that uses the following code to determine if the user clicked the submit button.

```
        // See if the value provider has the required prefix
        var hasPrefix = bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix(bindingContext.ModelName);
        var searchPrefix = (hasPrefix) ? bindingContext.ModelName + "." : string.Empty;

        var searchButton = GetValue(bindingContext, searchPrefix, "FTSearchButton");
        // If this value doesn't have value, the user didn't click the button so exit
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchButton)) {
            return null;
        }

    private static string GetValue(ModelBindingContext context, string prefix, string key) {
        var result = context.ValueProvider.GetValue(prefix + key);
        return result == null ? null : result.AttemptedValue;
    }
```

---

Here is the problem I'm having with this.  I have a page that displays a list of items.  I have a 'search' textbox and a submit button in an HTML form.  When the user enters text in the textbox and clicks the search button or uses the enter key, the page posts the form data via HTML [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods), and returns the first eight records found.  The page then displays page links for additional pages.  The problems is that when the user clicks a page link, the form data is all blank, and my filter information is lost (the form isn't posted with the form value when using these links).  So, I end up displaying a blank list of items (blank searches returns zero results) instead of paging the data.

By adding the check for the button name in my form data, I could determine whether or not to simply page the data, or do a new look up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I researched this last night and almost got somewhere.  Then this morning, I really did get somewhere and here's where I ended up.

Apparently the [W3C standards](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2) for form submission are pretty lax when describing the functionality as it relates to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button and submitting forms.  It seems they determined that

> When there is only one single-line text input field in a form, the user agent should accept Enter in that field as a request to submit the form.

So that leaves a lot of wiggle room for the browser makers.  Today, virtually all browsers support using the Enter key to submit a form, whether the form contains one or more single line text input boxes.

The problem I'm having is more or less unique to [Internet Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer), and only when the form contains one, single-line text input control.  For whatever reason, Microsoft decided that when Internet Explorer submits a form like this, it doesn't include the submit button's name/value pair in the post body. However, it does include the button's name/value pair if the user clicks the submit button --***or***-- uses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, and the form contains more than one single-line text input control.

So, the only solution I can think of or find suggested is to add a second single-line text input to my form, and then set the the style to

```css
visibility: hidden; display: none;
```

My form now has two single-line text input controls, so the form will post with the name/value pair in the form body, regardless of whether or not the user used the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key or clicked the submit button.

So, we have a workaround that was discovered by ASP.NET developers.  It seems the key/value pair is required by ASP.NET web-forms to fire the click event, so this work around isn't something new, albeit not my favorite way to do things.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't rely on this. There are plenty of documented bugs with this scenario. Just add a hidden field with `name='submit'`. That way it wouldn't be too hard to recode the backend.

```
<input type='hidden' name='submit' value='FTSearchButton'/>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's going to work for what I need.  I'm using an example where a model has a property named the same as the submit input control.  When the button is clicked, the property has a value when the MVC model is bound to the form.  You can see a full example of this here http://unboxedsolutions.com/sean/archive/2011/03/30/15977.aspx

Comment: Interesting. Btw, does this problem occur in every browser? As for a solution, you could try to overwrite the submit event entirely, and making sure the submit button value is being passed. I wouldnt know if that would work though as I am neither familiar with MVC-3 nor ASP.

Comment: I don’t see why you need to distinguish between using the enter key in a text field and using the submit button. At least it’s not obvious from the client-side code. If the server-side handler needs particular name=value pair in the form data, then it’s safest to include it in a hidden field and omit the 'name' attribute from the submit button.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela It has to do with the values when the page makes a post. When the button is clicked, the form values will contain the 'name' of the button. If the page makes a get request or post by another means, the form data will contain a null for the button.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - You commented, "I don’t see why you need to distinguish between using the enter key in a text field and using the submit button.". I don't need to distinguish between these two.  I need the opposite. I need then to appear the same on the server side.  Right now, they are distinguished.  I need to distinguish between the user using the enter key in a text field and the user using the paging links.